# iPhone/iPad retina image usage preferred?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, retina-display

I understand there is a file naming convention for standard images and retina (higher resolution) images. This is achieved by naming the file as `<filename>@2.jpg`, as an example.

Now I just ran a test on the iPad simulator that seems to suggest that it would be better to just use the higher resolution, period. The test was this: I had one full-screen image and one retina full-screen image. The low-res image simply has a "1" on it. The hi-res image shows "2" on it. Then I had the hi-res image load to fill the entire screen of the iPad simulator.

- *Result*: It seems like the entire retina image was displayed in the screen.
- *Expected result*: I expected the hi-res image to be partly cropped - I assumed the screen was too small to display the entire retina image.

Obvious questions:

1. Is my test flawed (am I missing something)?
2. And if this test can be verified, then why should we include 2 sets of images (standard and retina) if we can simply use retina? The only thing I see is that the retina images consume more memory, so it might be too much for devices that don't have retina displays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whether or not the retina (@2x) image is used depends *ONLY* on the scale factor (the amount of pixels per point) of the screen. Both iPad and iPhone have the same behavior.

You never reference the retina images directly. Instead you load them by saying

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];
```

If you are on a retina display the retina version of the image (myImage@2x.png) will be chosen for you. In either case the image takes up the same number of *points* on the screen. Both the retina and non-retina displays have the same number of *points*.

Comment: So what I'm asking is this: If a retina version of an image is displayed just fine on non-retina devices, why not just have one image (the retina version image), as opposed to having an extra copy (the non-retina + retina versions). Again, the only benefit i see in keeping both is the consume less resources on non-retina devices.

Comment: As you stated, #1 reason is memory consumption. Memory is very important, especially on older devices. Another reason is that the retina version is down-sampled to the smaller resolution when used on non-retina displays. This may not look optimal as you could have small details and textures in your images that look blurry when down-sampled. In those cases the designer will have small differences between the two images (like aligning things to pixel boundaries etc. ) so that they both look the best on their respective resolutions.

Comment: Concerning the memory: remember that an image in memory is not the same size it has on disk but the size of all the color channels for each pixels times the number of pixels. This is a much larger value. Think of it as 8 bits per color times three colors (four if the image has transparency) This means that a 100x100 image with transparency would be 8x4x100x100 bits = 40 kB in memory. If you instead use the retina version you would have a 160 kB image in memory. After only a few small images you are up in MB of memory and if you have big backgrounds you go there even faster.